# Functions returning arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I need my function to return an array that will then go into the next function. I know based on some research that I have to use a pointer to get this done. however when I run this code I get memory addresses or what appears to me memory addresses (if its not the address its a huge number) in my results.

The problem happens when the array needs to change functions. The two individual functions run fine on there own as intended.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int y = 0, x[10];
    int *p;
    y = capturingNumberTimesLoopRuns();
    p = PopulateArray(y);
    searchArray(x);
}

int capturingNumberTimesLoopRuns (void)
{
    int y = 0;
    while (y == 0) 
    {
        printf("Please enter the quantity of numbers you wish to enter.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
        if (y < 1 || y > 10)
        {
            printf("Invalid Selection! Please Try Again.\n");
            y = 0;
        }
    }
    return y;
}

int * PopulateArray(int y) 
{
    int i;
    int x[10];
    int a = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) 
    {
        printf("Please enter number %d: ", a);
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        a++;
    }
    return x;
}

void searchArray(int x[]) 
{
    int i, a = 0, numberOfTimes = 0, average = 0;
    for (i = 0; x[i] != 0; i++) 
    {
        if (x[i] % 3 == 0) 
        {
            a += x[i];
            numberOfTimes += 1;
        }
    }
    average = a / numberOfTimes;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("average = %d", average);
}
```

Comment: You cannot return the address of any variable with automatic storage in a function, since that storage is no longer allocated upon return from the function.  You have two options:  (1) Pass the array address as an argument to the function, or (2) Have the function allocate the storage with `malloc`, leaving it to the caller to free it later.

Comment: You can't return an array in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your research is correct. The way to handle operations on an array within a function is to pass a pointer to the array to your function. You can then operate on the array at-will in the function without the requirement of returning a pointer when your function return. (you can still return a pointer to the array for convenience of course)

Beyond passing a pointer to your array, you will need to pass the size of your array as well (or use a global to track the size of your array - not preferable as you want to avoid the use of globals unless totally necessary). For example, your `populatearray` function could be written as follows:

```
/* pass pointer to array and size to function */
int *populatearray (int *x, int sz) 
{
    int i, a = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)     {
        printf ("Please enter number %2d: ", a++);
        scanf ("%d", &x[i]);
    }

    return x;
}
```

(the return here is for convenience and is not required as your array is declared in `main()`)

This allows you to avoid dynamic allocation, maintaining a pointer to the allocated block of memory and the responsibility for freeing that memory when it is no longer needed. There is nothing wrong with dynamically allocating memory, but it is an additional layer of complication that new C programmers have to deal with.

A short example using your `populatearray` could work as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { MAXI = 10 };  /* avoid 'magic' numbers, use proper constants */

int *populatearray (int *x, int y);
void prnarray (int *x, int sz);

int main (void) {

    int x[MAXI] = {0};

    populatearray (x, MAXI);
    prnarray (x, MAXI);

    return 0;
}

/* pass pointer to array and size to function */
int *populatearray (int *x, int sz) 
{
    int i, a = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)     {
        printf ("Please enter number %2d: ", a++);
        scanf ("%d", &x[i]);
    }

    return x;
}

/* pass pointer to array and size to function */
void prnarray (int *x, int sz) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf (" x[%2d] : %d\n", i, x[i]);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_pass
Please enter number  1: 10
Please enter number  2: 20
Please enter number  3: 30
Please enter number  4: 40
Please enter number  5: 50
Please enter number  6: 60
Please enter number  7: 70
Please enter number  8: 80
Please enter number  9: 90
Please enter number 10: 100
 x[ 0] : 10
 x[ 1] : 20
 x[ 2] : 30
 x[ 3] : 40
 x[ 4] : 50
 x[ 5] : 60
 x[ 6] : 70
 x[ 7] : 80
 x[ 8] : 90
 x[ 9] : 100
```

(While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf))

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thank You for the detailed explanation. now i'm confident that my array values are fine and it is my searchArray function that is looking for any numbers divisible by three that is the reason I am getting the long numbers as my result.

Comment: I have even fixed that now my for loop was not using size to iterate through the array. But really appreciate the explanation I was struggling with the pointer aspect and I think that this will help me with that as well as I am just a beginner.

Comment: You will get it. C just takes time, but it is well worth it. Remember, a *pointer* is nothing more than a variable that holds the *address-of* something else as its value. E.g. `int a = 5;` declares `a` with an *immediate-value* of `5`. Then, `int *b = &a;` simply declares the variable `b` (a pointer) that holds the *address-of* `a` as its value. In C you can only pass a single value as a function parameter, or return. So in order to pass an array to a function, the array variable is converted to a pointer (a variable holding the address of the first element as its value. `:)` Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The array is destroyed when the function returns due to its auto storage. Try allocating memory dynamically from the heap (ie malloc()) as:

```
int * PopulateArray(int y) 
{
    int i;
    int *x = malloc(10*sizeof(int));

    int a = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++) 
    {
        printf("Please enter number %d: ", a);
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        a++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: **Don't use explicit `malloc` casting!**